# SharpDX is filling entire form instead of drawing triangle

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I'm trying to write simple DirectX 11 app using C# and SharpDX. I wanted to test basic drawing but when i run the program, i will get entire form filled with red color. When i change the vertices its drawing unwanted shapes. Clear color works.

I tried changing some properties but nothing helps.

Here is the code:

```
    private Vector3[] Vertices = new Vector3[]
    {
        new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0), new Vector3(0, -0.5f, 0)
    };
    private D3D11.Buffer VertexBuffer;

    public Game()
    {
        RenderForm = new RenderForm("Test Form");
        RenderForm.ClientSize = new Size(Width, Height);
        RenderForm.AllowUserResizing = false;

        InitDeviceResources();
        InitShaders();
        InitVertexBuffer();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        RenderLoop.Run(RenderForm, RenderCallback);
    }

    private void InitVertexBuffer()
    {
        VertexBuffer = D3D11.Buffer.Create<Vector3>(Device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, Vertices);
    }

    private void InitShaders()
    {
        using (ShaderBytecode vertexShaderBytecode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("vertexShader.hlsl", "main", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlags.Debug))
        {
            InputSignature = ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vertexShaderBytecode);

            VertexShader = new VertexShader(Device, vertexShaderBytecode);
        }

        using (ShaderBytecode pixelShaderBytecode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("pixelShader.hlsl", "main", "ps_4_0", ShaderFlags.Debug))
        {
            PixelShader = new PixelShader(Device, pixelShaderBytecode);
        }

        Context.VertexShader.Set(VertexShader);
        Context.PixelShader.Set(PixelShader);

        Context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;

        InputLayout = new InputLayout(Device, InputSignature, InputElements);
        Context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = InputLayout;
    }

    private void InitDeviceResources()
    {
        ModeDescription backBufferDesc = new ModeDescription(Width, Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm);

        SwapChainDescription swapChainDesc = new SwapChainDescription()
        {
            BufferCount = 1,
            IsWindowed = true,
            OutputHandle = RenderForm.Handle,
            ModeDescription = backBufferDesc,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
        };

        D3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None, swapChainDesc, out Device, out SwapChain);
        Context = Device.ImmediateContext;

        Viewport = new Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
        Context.Rasterizer.SetViewport(Viewport);

        using (Texture2D backBuffer = SwapChain.GetBackBuffer<Texture2D>(0))
        {
            RenderTarget = new RenderTargetView(Device, backBuffer);
        }
    }

    private void RenderCallback()
    {
        Draw();
    }

    private void Draw()
    {
        Context.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(RenderTarget);

        Context.ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTarget, new Color4(0, 0, 1, 1));

        Context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(VertexBuffer, Utilities.SizeOf<Vector3>(), 0));

        Context.Draw(Vertices.Count(), 0);

        SwapChain.Present(1, PresentFlags.None);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried drawing the triangle clockwise instead of counter-clockwise? (Talking about the order of your vertices)

Comment: Also it seems you are setting the viewport from 0, 0 to `width, height` but placing some of the vertices in negative space. This will probably result in only a part of the triangle being rendered (if it were to be correctly rendered)

Comment: Yes i tried it. The viewport is normalized to -1, 1(Left upper corner) and  1, -1(Bottom right corner) so 0, -0.5 is on form.

Comment: Could you post the shader code?

Comment: Vertex shader: `float4 main(float4 position : POSITION) : SV_POSITION
{
 return position;
}`

Comment: Pixel shader: `float4 main(float4 position : SV_POSITION) : SV_TARGET
{
 return float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}`

Comment: @MatějVaniš Just wanted to point out that `zero` isn't actually `-0.5` in screen space. `0, 0` in screen space can be represented by `Width / 2, Height / 2` in pixel space.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this. There must be `Format.R32G32B32_Float` instead of `Format.R32G32B32A32_Float`